# como criar várias tags li e setar id para elas através de um click de um botão?

Tags: javascript

```
const itListAdd = document.querySelector('#itemListAdd');
let itemList = '';
const nmList = document.querySelector('#nameList');
const unorderedList = document.querySelector('#ulList');
const createLi = document.createElement('li');
let i = 0;
let li = '';

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(itListAdd.value == 'add to the list' || itListAdd.value == ''){
        alert('Por favor digite o nome do item');
        nmList.value = 'add to the list';
    }else{
        
        
        itemList = itListAdd.value;
        unorderedList.appendChild(createLi);
        document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].setAttribute('id', `item${i}`);
        li = document.querySelector(`#item${i}`);
        li.innerHTML =  itemList;
        i++;
        
         
        itListAdd.value = 'add to the list';
    }
});
```

Comment: eu consigo criar um li com isso porém quando clico para criar a segunda li da o seguinte erro "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')", js consegue capturar o valor digitado na input mas não chega a criar o segundo item da lista.

Answer (score -1):

Ao criar o `const createLi` você está criando a referência para um único elemento (pois é **const**). Ou seja, ele está se perdendo nas referências.
Para conseguir o objetivo desejado (criar ítens de listas com ids próprios e únicos), deixo o exemplo abaixo:
Observe que através do CSS está sendo exibido o ID de cada li ao lado de seu conteúdo.

```js
const inputItem = document.querySelector('#itemListAdd');
const lista = document.querySelector('#ulList');
const btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    const numeroFilhos = Array.from(lista.querySelectorAll("li")).length;
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.value = inputItem.value;
    item.id = `item-${numeroFilhos+1}`;
    item.innerHTML = inputItem.value;
    lista.appendChild(item);
  }
);

inputItem.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if(this.value){
    btnAdd.disabled = false
  }else{
    btnAdd.disabled = true
  }
});
```

```css
li::after{
  content: ' Id atribuído: '  attr(id)
}
```

```html
Lista: <ul id="ulList"></ul>
Item da List: <input id="itemListAdd" value="" placeholder="Informe o item da lista" /> <button id="btnAdd" disabled>Add</button>
```

Comment: primeiramente obg pela ajuda, tenho uma duvida, na linha onde vc cria a variável "numeroFilhos" vc utiliza a função Array para acessar todos as tags filhas de lista ?

Comment: Na verdade, utilizei essa estratégia para obter o total de elementos que ja existem. Como o `querySelectorAll` retorna um `NodeList`, é mais fácil fazer isso do que iterar pela lista e contar um a um.